# How best to replace xpath selectors with elements generated by EXTJS with Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, extjs, selenium-webdriver

Alright I am trying to optimize my tests. This may be simply a limitation of Selenium Webdriver but I was never able to get a solid answer to that point so I am asking the question directly. The reason this is coming up is because for my tests I have to use xpath selectors. Recently I have had to go back and change all of my selectors throughout all of my tests because a div was added somewhere, or we upgraded to extJS 6 which rewrote the framework. Essentially in the example below I went from using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span")).getText();
```

to

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/span")).getText();
```

As you can see the changes were small but I had to make them to over a hundred tests, some of which were far more complicated. Here is an example of the code I am testing against.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="syn-scheduletree-body" class="class="x-panel-body x-grid-no-row-lines x-grid-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default"">
            <div class="x-tree-view x-fit-item x-tree-view-default x-unselectable x-scroller">
                <div class="x-grid-item-container">
//Here is Example 1
                    <table id="treeview-1068-record-158">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                <td class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                    <span class="x-tree-node-text">
                                        Example 1
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
//Here is Example 2
                    <table id="treeview-1068-record-159">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                <td class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                    <span class="x-tree-node-text">
                                        Example 2
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
//Here is Example 3
                    <table id="treeview-1068-record-160">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                <td class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row">
                                    <span class="x-tree-node-text">
                                        Example 3
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In one of my tests I have to go through and click a save button which created a new instance within the list in the table. Because of this I cannot rely on any hard coded xpath as the numebr generated along with the new div will be different every time. So I have included the following logic

```
String i = 1;
while (i < 100) {
    String temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div/table[" + i + "]/tbody/tr/td/span")).getText();
    if (temp.contains("Example 2")) {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

This incorporates java logic to find an element within a list as well as store the location of that element with the String i.

The question I have is is there a better way. I had a co-worker who mentioned recently that if I could use a selector to select something in the javascript this could all be made easier, and it would require less maintenance than xpath. I simple do not know how to do this, where to start, if it is possible. I can provide more info if needed. Please just let me know if you have any suggestions. This is not a released product yet, so I am looking at a lot of feature changes and additions within short periods of time prompting me to rewrite most every test due to the nature of xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to find Elements based on their text with Seleniums xpaths, this should give you the Element youre looking for:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(), 'Example 2')]"));
```

Comment: Okay that seems to work, though I took out everything in the xpath up to the span such as

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), '" + report + "')]")).click();

I have a question though. What if what I needed was to click an anchor <a>? I already tried and clicking the span within the anchor does not work. How could I apply the code you gave me to click the anchor that contains a span which contains a certain set of text?

Comment: @Senator1891 i dont know exactly, you could try acikojevics solution, but i dont know if it works.What i found is, that you can go an element up in the xpath with "..", your line would look like this then: "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), '" + report + "')]/..")).click();"

Answer (score 0):

@Senator1891 
I can't make a comment so I'll put it here.

> How could I apply the code you gave me to click the anchor that
>   contains a span which contains a certain set of text?

Good solution in this cases is `xpath("//a[contains(., '" + report + "')]")`

This `.` will find text in element inside `<a>`, which is `<span>` in your case.